# publish point cloud xyz

Tags: kinect, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i wrote a ros node for kinect pointcloud 2 to pass through filter and publish it to a topic. But when i run the node, it give me this error

/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference::type boost::shared_ptr::operator*() const [with T = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference::type = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

I cant seem to fix this problem. please help

```
class Listener
{

public:

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_passthrough;

    void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& kinect_output);

};
// end class

void Listener::callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& kinect_output)
{
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr pc2 (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2());

    pcl_conversions::toPCL (*kinect_output, *pc2);
    
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2 ());
    
    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
    sor.setInputCloud (pc2);
    sor.setLeafSize(0.01f,0.01f,0.01f);
    sor.filter(*cloud_filtered);// filter the point cloud
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloudXYZ (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);//object cloud for point cloud type XYZ
    pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(*cloud_filtered,*cloudXYZ);
    
    //create passthrough filter object
    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZ> pass;
    pass.setInputCloud (cloudXYZ);
    pass.setFilterFieldName("z");
    pass.setFilterLimits(0.5, 1.5);
    pass.filter(*cloud_passthrough);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init (argc, argv, "PointCloud2_to_pointCloudXYZ");

    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    Listener listener;
    
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >("/filtered", 1000);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    cloud -> points = listener.cloud_passthrough->points;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);    
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe <sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/camera/depth/points",1000,&Listener::callback, &listener);
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        pub.publish (cloud);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }//end while loop   
    return 0;
}//end main
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206116/publish-point-cloud-xyz/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-03-27**:
Must be the intraprocesd in node. How can i go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Assertion 'px != 0' failed.` means that you're using a `boost::shared_ptr` before it's initialized somewhere.

In particular, I notice that you're not initializing `cloud_passthrough` anywhere. You should probably write a constructor for your `Listener` class and initialize it there.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9